# ORDER BY with two expressions

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by

There is an `SQL` query with `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY someColumn DESC NULLS LAST, NULLIF(anotherColumn->>'someNumField', '')::float';
```

So, here are two types of sorting. First one is performed, then the second. I want the second sort to be performed under certain conditions.
How to do second sorting only if that value is not `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a CASE expression in your order by

```
ORDER BY someColumn DESC NULLS LAST, CASE when logic then 'a' else 'b' end
```